# How can I get my array class instance to use initializer list to initialize the array

Tags: c++

I am trying to write an array class similar to the one in standard lib for practice. I want to be able to initialize my array class by using an initializer list, but I don't what code to add to my class to do that. I am confused because there are multiple elements in the initializer list but only container to hold the data.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, int size>
class Array
{
private:
    T data[size];

public:
    Array() {};
};

int main()
{
    //I want to do this but it currently doesn't allow me to do this.
    //I need someone to tell me what i need to add to my class to be able
    //to do this
    //Aarray<int, 5> a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 

    //The above line should do
    //a.data[0] = 1;
    //a.data[1] = 2;
    //a.data[2] = 3;
    //a.data[3] = 4;
    //a.data[4] = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways

- make your class aggregate:

  ```
  template<typename T, int size>
  class Array
  {
  public:
      T data[size];
  };
  ```
- Provide constructor which accept `{..}` such as

```
template<typename T, int size>
class Array
{
private:
    T data[size];

public:
    Array(const T (&data)[size]);
    //Array(std::initializer_list<T> ini);

    // ...
};
```

Comment: What is `Array(const T (&data)[size]);` called? Where can I read about what it is?

Comment: It says `no instance of constructor "Array<T, size>::Array [with T=int, size=5]" matches the argument list` when I add that constructor.

Comment: @user14859499 define constructor as `Array(const T (&d)[size]) { for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) data[i] = d[i]; }`  and in *main* `Array<int, 5> a({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});` What about also to use `size_t`rather than `int` in your template class ?

Comment: @bruno Thanks it works, but I don't understand it. How is `T(&d) [size]` working?